# Magento 2 > cannot login to admin area (php7) but php 5.6 gives Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in

Tags: magento2, admin, url-rewrite, login, installation

I installed Magento 2.0.2, via installatron service (automated on Direct Admin), but I cannot access admin area. CSS/JS looks ok, but admin cannot login on php 7.0.6. When I switched to php 5.6 I'm getting

```
Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64
```

Where to fix it? Since any other options are not working so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You php do not have `intl` extension. You can verify it by run `php -i`.

In many cases this problem appear when you have different php version/configurations for apache and cli. For example if use install MAMP on MacOsX that you will have different version. To use php in this case you need specify full path to php like `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php`

To change it you need to do  folowing steps:

Edit  `~/.bash_profile` and add

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x/bin:$PATH
```

where `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x` should be patch to your latest wersion

In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

In Terminal, type in `which php` and look for the updated patch. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

Comment: I have intl installed. I checked. I even did test before I install Magento manually from zip - and it shows that all requirements are met

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, running the cron / indexer:reindex
The sollution I found was to run xampp's shell and there write the code. Otherwise, on command prompt ( Windows ) it would give me the same error.